# SAPUI5 SmartTable pressItem event is triggered twice

Tags: sapui5

I have the issue that the `pressItem` event is triggered twice at smarttable ( sapui5).

The smarttable has type `ResponsiveTable`.

```js
 onAfterRendering : function(){
        var tTable = this.byId("LineItemsSmartTable");
        var oTable = this.byId("LineItemsSmartTable").getTable(); 
        oTable.setMode(sap.m.ListMode.SingleSelectMaster);
        oTable.onAfterRendering = function(){
          this.attachItemPress(function(oEvent){ alert( "Pressed" ); });
        };
            
        // var fnItemPress = function(){ alert("press2") };   
        tTable.attachDataReceived(function(){
             var aItems = oTable.getItems();
             if(aItems.length === 0 ) return;
             $.each(aItems, function(oIndex, oItem) {
                //oItem.detachPress(fnItemPress);
                 oItem.setType("Active");
          // oItem.attachPress(fnItemPress);
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `onAfterRendering` is not being called already `onInit` then reconsider renaming the function **oTable.onAfterRendering**.

`onAfterRendering` is already called in the controller lifecycle, you could try creating a new function and then calling that in `onAfterRendering`.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28706464/7626277)

```js
onAfterRendering: function() {
    this.tableItems();
  },

  tableItems: function() {
    var tTable = this.byId("LineItemsSmartTable");
    var oTable = this.byId("LineItemsSmartTable").getTable();
    oTable.setMode(sap.m.ListMode.SingleSelectMaster);

    oTable.attachItemPress(function(oEvent) {
      alert("Pressed");
    });

    tTable.attachDataReceived(function() {
      var aItems = oTable.getItems();
      if (aItems.length === 0) return;
      $.each(aItems, function(oIndex, oItem) {
        oItem.setType("Active");
      });
    });

  }
```